# Missed prayer and what to do now?

Tags: salat-qada

I set an alarm for fajr and went to sleep. I woke up at the alarm time but was not in a clear state. I saw it was 6 pm and turned the alarn off. I can't remember if I firgot to pray but I have a feeling there was some sort of forgetfulness.
Now I don't know what to do. How much prayers should I do to make up for this? How should I ask for forgiveness for this and how long for? Can I still pray the fajr or not?

Comment: The duplicate answer covers your inquiry.

Comment: It does not necessarily cover what I wanted. It says if you intentionally missed fajr then you can't make it up. I drfinitely did not want to miss fajr intentionally but I did wake up. Also I can't remember if I was forgetful of prayer or if I were not when I were awake.

Comment: it says if you missed a prayer you can make it up once you've remembered it. I don't know what you are reading.

Comment: Yes I know but the things is it says if you missed a prayer out of forgetfulness. I can not remember whether I was forgetful or not since I had just woke up to the alarm. Also take in to mind that the alarm was during fajr time but when I woke up I can't remember the state I was in.

Comment: I still don't know what you are reading. The answer is there and we don't need a different one.

Comment: Yes the answer says if you missed a prayer DUE TO FORGETFULNESS or if you slept past the time you can make it up. The thing is I do not know if I were forgetful or not and I definitely did not sleep past the time. If there is another part that has past my eye please say so but so far I can not seem to find anything.

Comment: If someone knows an answer please help I'm desperate

Comment: The duplicate answer says clearly "*you can pray a missed prayer or a prayer you remembered after missing it at any time according most madhhabs while some prefer to pray them at a time where prayer is allowed*" so this is what you have to do.

Comment: @Sassir Isn't this incorrect? I thought if you were forgetful DURING the prayer time or if you overslept. This suggests that if you know the prayer has started and then fall alseep or something you can still perform it

Comment: No the hadith provided is crystal clear and says "once you remember" so the time when you remembered your missed prayer is open it can be at any time.

Comment: @Sassir Yes I know that is what the hadith says but the things is when I woke up for my alarm at Fajr time, I am not sure if I knew it was Fajr time then or if I didn't. If i did know then what should I do since I went back to sleep but if I didn't then I can make it up. The things is I can't remember if I did know it was Fajr time or not